# XAMPP mysql connection is refusing after installation of Net Beans IDE

Tags: xampp

I have installed Net Beans IDE.But it makes my XAMPP server MySQL non function able.Please see attachment.How I can configure to XAMPP with my old mysql database.I have useful data on my previous database.Any helps ?[image]

Comment: You're testing everything at the same time, what leads to false assumptions like NetBeans IDE fiddling with other programs. To begin with, test whether your service is running... with your own eyes—don't rely on some third-party app that runs on a complex stack.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the information provided is completely unrelated to the problem, thus this question is unlikely to help anyone else in the future; on the contrary, it'll probably lead to confusion.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario..Hello It is related to correct configuration solution of XAMPP  installation with Net Beans.Why you said its unrelated ?Am I missing something ?

Comment: Feel free to add a comment to the accepted answer if you have any question about it. No matter what you think, NetBeans will not fiddle with your MySQL server instance.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  NetBeans will not fiddle with your MySQL server instance 
>>>I am sure that netBeans use mysql server.Can you please explain more ?

Comment: Blue elephants don't exist. Can you prove that?

Comment: Where php don;t exist on netbeans ?if you say yes then FYI netbeans is a tool that provides php environment too for execution of php files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually occurs when you have wrong credentials in your [*.../phpMyadmin/config.inc.php*].

If you have **another mysql instance installed** and the username and the password that you use in this file is different,
change the username and the password in the above file to match.

***Edit:*** Try running `cmd` as an administrator and type `sc delete mysql`.
Restart xammp.

Comment: @Ashish Hav u try the **Edit**

Comment: Yes,It shows ....C:\Users\user>sc delete mysql
[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:

Access is denied.

Comment: Did you run it as an admin?

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have changed password of new installed My Sql server 5.0 with the old password using by XAMPP with the help of this link  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html.Now Php my admin is working fine.I appreciate your work

Comment: @Ashish Anytime mate.